# Having trouble installing HDBCLI in to python 3.10

Tags: python, driver, installation-package

I am trying to install `hdbcli` in to my python jupyter notebook and feel like I have exhausted my attempts.

Have tried:

```
pip install hdbcli
```

Keep getting this error, my python version is 3.10:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000203FCF39BA0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/hdbcli/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000203FCF39E70>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/hdbcli/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000203FCF39FF0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/hdbcli/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000203FCF3A0E0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/hdbcli/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000203FCF3A260>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/hdbcli/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdbcli (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hdbcli
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is suggesting that you have connectivity issues as the client is not able to reach `pypi.org`. This may be related to internet connectivity, firewalls, etc.

Despite the last message of the trace, it does not imply, that `hdbcli` is not compatible with Python 3.10 as mentioned in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77441086/python-notebook-query-to-dbeaver-to-sap-hana).