# Python notebook query to Dbeaver to SAP HANA

Tags: python, database-connection, hana, dbeaver

I have a dbeaver connection to SAP HANA database but want to use dbeaver as a 'middle man' to  send python notebook queries to and pull out of SAP HANA.

I have python 3.10 installed and it won't let me install hdbcli and can't download any SAP ODBC drivers either for some reason.

I have the host name, port no, user name and password to the SAP HANA database connection from DBeaver.

At my wits end trying to extract data from SAP HANA via jupyter notebook (this is my tool of preference), so would appreciate any input that might resolve my issue!

Tried installing hdbcli in Python but doesn't look like there is a version for python 3.10.

Can't download SAP ODBC driver as it costs money to get the license.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the client package for SAP HANA under the terms of the developer license agreement [here](https://tools.eu1.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools). It includes the ODBC driver and does not cost any money.

The page also includes information on how to install `hdbcli` via `pip`. However, I would recommend to try out [hana_ml](https://pypi.org/project/hana-ml/), which is based on hdbcli, but offers additional functionality to interact with in-database machine learning and multi-model data.

Both, `hdbcli` and `hana_ml` are compatible with Python 3.10. Your [installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77416475/having-trouble-installing-hdbcli-in-to-python-3-10) seems related to connectivity rather than incompatibility.